# Template parse errors: X is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-template

I have some issue with my component 'countries-menu'.
The component works fine in another page, so the problem is not the component (I'm not sure but I think my component is okay).
Maybe there is a conflict in declaration, or I don't know.

My component **HTML** :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>{{ 'NEW_EVENT_COUNTRY_HEADER' | translate }}*</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="selectCountry(country)" formControlName="country">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

My component **TS**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the CountriesMenuComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
 * Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'countries-menu',
  templateUrl: 'countries-menu.html',
})
export class CountriesMenuComponent {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() currentEvent?: Object;
  private countries: Object;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private translate: TranslateService) {
    const url = 'assets/countries/' + this.translate.currentLang + '.json';
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((data) => {
      this.countries =  data;
    },                                 (error) => {
      this.httpClient.get('assets/countries/en.json').subscribe((data) => {
        this.countries =  data;
      });
    });
  }

  selectCountry(country: any) {
    if (this.currentEvent !== undefined) this.currentEvent[country] = country;
  }
}
```

**components.module.ts** I export the component (there is a lot of other component but I remove them to save place)

```
import { CountriesMenuComponent } from './countries-menu/countries-menu';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [IonicModule],
  exports: [...,
    CountriesMenuComponent],
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Then in my **Module where I want to use** the componant, I use the declaration array.

```
import { CountriesMenuComponent } from '../../components/countries-menu/countries-menu';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PersonalInformationPage,
    CountriesMenuComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(PersonalInformationPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ],
  providers: [
    // Keep this to enable Ionic's runtime error handling during development
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    LeadService,
  ],
})
export class PersonalInformationPageModule { }
```

But when I use my HTML selector I have this error : **Template parse errors: 'countries-menu' is not a known element:**

**HTML**

```
...
<ion-col>
  <countries-menu [form]="form"></countries-menu>
</ion-col>
...
```

I did the same thing in another webpage, and it's work fine.
I tried to put the declaration in app.module.ts, to have access in all the application but it do not work.
I don't know how to fix that, maybe I missed something ? I don't know but it's working fine in another page, without anything else.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Could you please also post the HTML that is causing the issue ?

Comment: @shining you forgot to import `ComponentsModule` into `PersonalInformationPageModule `.

Comment: Could you please also post the HTML that is causing the issue ? : <countries-menu></countries-menu> (event I put @Input, it do not work)

Comment: @shining you forgot to import ComponentsModule into PersonalInformationPageModule .  : I put it here : 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PersonalInformationPage,
    **CountriesMenuComponent**,
  ],

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare a class that's already declared in another module. See this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-classes-should-i-not-add-to-declarations). When I read "I did the same thing in another webpage, and it's work fine", I understand that you made this mistake. Therefore, `CountriesMenuComponent` must be declared only in `ComponentsModule`.

Try to declare your component in `ComponentsModule` and import this module in `PersonalInformationPageModule` :

**components.module.ts**

```
import { CountriesMenuComponent } from './countries-menu/countries-menu';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      CountriesMenuComponent,
      ...          
  ],
  imports: [IonicModule],
  exports: [...,
    CountriesMenuComponent],
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

**PersonalInformationPageModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PersonalInformationPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(PersonalInformationPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ],
  providers: [
    // Keep this to enable Ionic's runtime error handling during development
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    LeadService,
  ],
})
export class PersonalInformationPageModule { }
```

Comment: yes. I tried your fix in my other page where the component currently works, and it's do not work.

Comment: Could you provide a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: No sorry, it's a confidential project :/

Comment: I tried to reproduce a similar situation : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v2pzyy

Comment: Thank you I wiil look at your code, really thank a lot !

Comment: Np ! keep me informed ;)